# Priority Queue using Heap

Tags: c++, c++11, heap, priority-queue

I have written this code after studying from **Introduction to Algorithm**. I am unable to find out what is the problem with the code. I have written the code for `heapsort` and it runs well. `heap_extract_max()` will return the maximum value. `heap_increase_key()` increase the priority of an element. [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174633/minimum-priority-queue-using-singly-linked-list/174641#174641) I have written program for priority queue using singly linked list which runs well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void max_heapify(std::vector<T>& array, size_t index)
{
  size_t largest;
  size_t left  = (2*index) + 1;
  size_t right = left + 1;

  if(left < array.size() && array[left] > array[index])
    largest = left;
  else
    largest = index;

  if(right < array.size() && array[right] > array[largest])
    largest = right;

  if(largest != index)
  {
    int tmp = array[index];
    array[index] = array[largest];
    array[largest] = tmp;
    max_heapify(array, largest);
  }
}

template<typename T>
void build_max_heap(std::vector<T>& array)
{
  for(size_t i = (array.size()/2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  max_heapify(array, i);
}

template<typename T>
T heap_maximum(std::vector<T>& array)
{
  return array[0];
}

template<typename T>
T heap_extract_max(std::vector<T>& array)
{
  if(array.size() < 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Heap Underflow \n";
  }
  else
  {
    T max = array[0];
    array[0] = array[array.size() - 1];
    //array.size() = array.size() - 1;
    max_heapify(array, 1);
    return max;
  }
}

template<typename T>
void heap_increase_key(std::vector<T>& array, size_t index, T value)
{
  if(value < array[index])
  {
    std::cerr <<"New value is smaller than the current value\n";
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    array[index] = value;
    while(index > 0 && array[(index/2) - 1] < array[index])
    {
      std::swap(array[index], array[(index/2) - 1]);
      index = (index/2) - 1;
    }
  }
}

template<typename T>
void max_heap_insert(std::vector<T>& array, T value)
{
  array[array.size()] = -1;
  heap_increase_key(array, array.size(), value);
}

int main()
{
std::vector<int> v({1, 2, 6, 3, 7});
build_max_heap(v);
std::cout << heap_extract_max(v)<<"\n";
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
  std::cout << v[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n";
}
```

It is not showing any output. I am writing commands

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 priorityqueue.cpp -o priorityqueue
$ ./priorityqueue
```

Comment: Warnings and debugger might mention things like "not all control paths return a value" during the compile, or "subscript out of range" during runtime. Debugging your code is your job, but it's much easier if you use the tools available.

Comment: How did you figure out that "it's not showing any output"? Maybe does it enter an infinite loop in `heap_extract_max()`? Try looking at the process list whether your program is still running.

Comment: y'all are too nice.  If you make coder use -Wall and gdb, it will go a lot farther than handing someone a fish.

Comment: If this is for academia, I can certainly understand the restriction of not using the `std::priority_queue` container adapter (the obvious choice for eliminating literally *all* of this code). However, setting that aside, I don't suppose using [`std::make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), [`std::push_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap), and [`std::pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) are options. It would eliminate nearly all of this code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with the below function what will be return for if case
because of that

> Control may reach end of non-void function

```
template<typename T>
T heap_extract_max(std::vector<T>& array)
{
    if(array.size() < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Heap Underflow \n";
    }
    else
    {
        T max = array[0];
        array[0] = array[array.size() - 1];
        //array.size() = array.size() - 1;
        max_heapify(array, 1);
        return max;
    }
}
```

Add return -1 or anything else for if case

```
if(array.size() < 0)
{
    std::cerr << "Heap Underflow \n";
    return -1;
}
```

second problem

```
for(size_t i = (array.size()/2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

> Comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true

Try changing to:(as suggested by Serge Rogatch)

```
for(int64_t i = (int64_t(array.size())/2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

As  well as there is problem with extracting it
Before change result was

```
7
2 3 6 1 2 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Because of wrong handling of remove .Handled removed properly in below code

```
template<typename T>
T heap_extract_max(std::vector<T>& array)
{
    if(array.size() < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Heap Underflow \n";
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        T max = array[0];
        array[0] = array[array.size() - 1];
        array.erase(std::remove(array.begin(), array.end(), array[0]),
                   array.end());
        array.shrink_to_fit();
        max_heapify(array, 0);
        return max;
    }
}
```

After change

```
7
6 3 1 2 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your program enters an infinite loop or crashes. I see a problem here:

```
for(size_t i = (array.size()/2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Because `i` is unsigned, it is always `i >= 0`. Also, for `array.size() <= 1`, you initialize it with some large positive integer, because `i` tries to go negative, but `size_t` is never negative, so the number wraps.

Try changing to:

```
for(int64_t i = (int64_t(array.size())/2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Also you seem to confuse `0`- and `1`-based array indexing, and you should do `array.pop_back()` in place of `//array.size() = array.size() - 1;`. Furthermore, it seems you intended `array[1]` instead of `array[0]` here:

```
T max = array[0];
array[0] = array[array.size() - 1];
```

If you stick with `1`-based indexing, you should place and keep a dummy element at index `0` in your array:

```
std::vector<int> v({/*dummy*/-1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 7});
```

Array size is never negative, so you don't need `if(array.size() < 0)` and what's in `then` clause.

Though `0`-based indexing is more natural in C++ and heap can be implemented with it too. For this you would need to revise all the index arithmetic like:

```
size_t left  = (2*index) + 1;
size_t right = left + 1;
```

and

```
array[(index/2) - 1]
```